# Laravel pusher Broadcasting not sending events

Tags: php, laravel, pusher, laravel-5.3

I have quite the unusual Broadcasting problem with my app, I have it synced over Dropbox and on my laptop I can run it and it sends the events to the pusher server, however, on my desktop it does not. I use the same version of XAMPP server, same migrations etc. Anybody who could suggest anything? Code provided down below.

#### App\Events\TodoCreated.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Models\Todo;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class TodoCreated extends Event implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $todo;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Todo $todo)
    {
        $this->todo = $todo;
    }

    /*public function broadcastWith()
    {

    }*/

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return ['team.' . $this->todo->team_id . '.todos'];
    }
}
```

#### config/broadcasting.php

```
'connections' => [

    'pusher' => [
        'driver' => 'pusher',
        'key' => env('PUSHER_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_SECRET'),
        'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => 'eu',
            'encrypted' => true
        ],
    ],
```

#### .env

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
...
PUSHER_APP_ID=<app_id>
PUSHER_KEY=<key>
PUSHER_SECRET=<secret>
```

- I fire the event using `event(new App\Events\TodoCreate($todo))` where `$todo` is an instance of `App\Models\Todo`
- I have enabled the BroadcastServiceProvider in the config/app.php file
- I rune `php artisan queue:work --timeout=0` and see that the events are registered and successfully run but nothing is recieved on my pusher debug panel

Answer (score 2):

I code test pusher Broadcasting sending events and It is ok.  I use Laravel 5.1. Please view follow code bellow

**1. file config (or config file .env) broadcasting.php**

```
'default' => env('BROADCAST_DRIVER', 'pusher'),
    'connections' => [

        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_KEY','xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_SECRET','xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID','xxxxxx'),
            'options' => [
                //
            ],
        ],
```

**2. Router**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('/broadcast', function() {
    event(new \App\Events\TestEvent('Broadcasting in Laravel using Pusher!'));

});
```

3. **TestEvent.php**

```
namespace App\Events;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class TestEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    public $text;

    public function __construct($text)
    {
        $this->text = $text;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return ['test-channel'];
    }
}
```

**4. Composer**

```
"require": {...,"pusher/pusher-php-server": "^2.2",}
```

5. **welcome.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Laravel</title>

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <style>
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
            }

            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                width: 100%;
                display: table;
                font-weight: 100;
                font-family: 'Lato';
            }

            .container {
                text-align: center;
                display: table-cell;
                vertical-align: middle;
            }

            .content {
                text-align: center;
                display: inline-block;
            }

            .title {
                font-size: 96px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="title">Laravel 5</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="//js.pusher.com/3.0/pusher.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var pusher = new Pusher("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
        var channel = pusher.subscribe('test-channel');
        channel.bind('App\\Events\\TestEvent', function(data) {
            console.log(data.text);
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

**I Hope help You!**

Comment: Seems you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45877837/how-can-i-make-realtime-notification-for-user-who-are-not-login